# Disable memcached from php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, caching, memcached

Hello i am working on cms written on php laravel framework and it hase memcached cache service.

I need to relocate website from virtual server where memcached can be run to new hosting so i need to disable/avoid memcache, cause website is not that complex to use memcached. How can i avoid cache and change my php files.

here are what i am workin with

**index.php**

```
 <?php

$_PATH = __DIR__ . '/..';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels nice to relax.
|
 */
require $_PATH . '/core/bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to make jigar PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
 */

$app = require_once $_PATH . '/core/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
 */
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);

?>
```

**app.php**

```
    <?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Create The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The first thing we will do is create a new CMS application instance
| which serves as the "glue" for all the components of CMS, and is
| the IoC container for the system binding all of the various parts.
|
*/

$app = new ITDCMS\System\Foundation\Application(
    realpath($_PATH)
);


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Bind Important Interfaces
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, we need to bind some important interfaces into the container so
| we will be able to resolve them when needed. The kernels serve the
| incoming requests to this application from both the web and CLI.
|
*/
$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
    ITDCMS\System\App\Http\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    ITDCMS\System\App\Console\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    ITDCMS\System\App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Return The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This script returns the application instance. The instance is given to
| the calling script so we can separate the building of the instances
| from the actual running of the application and sending responses.
|
*/
return $app;
?>
```

**autoload.php**

```
  <?php

define('ITDCMS_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Composer Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader
| for our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll require it
| into the script here so that we do not have to worry about the
| loading of any our classes "manually". Feels great to relax.
|
*/

require $_PATH.'/system/App/helpers.php';

require $_PATH.'/system/App/Common/Autoloader.php';

require $_PATH.'/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Include The Compiled Class File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| To dramatically increase your application's performance, you may use a
| compiled class file which contains all of the classes commonly used
| by a request. The Artisan "optimize" is used to create this file.
|
*/

$compiledPath = __DIR__.'/cache/compiled.php';

if (file_exists($compiledPath)) {
    require $compiledPath;
}
?>
```

**cache.php**

```
    <?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Cache Store
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default cache connection that gets used while
    | using this caching library. This connection is used when another is
    | not explicitly specified when executing a given caching function.
    |
    */
    'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cache Stores
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define all of the cache "stores" for your application as
    | well as their drivers. You may even define multiple stores for the
    | same cache driver to group types of items stored in your caches.
    |
    */

    'stores' => [

        'apc' => [
            'driver' => 'apc',
        ],

        'array' => [
            'driver' => 'array',
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table'  => 'cache',
            'connection' => null,
        ],

        'file' => [
            'driver' => 'file',
            'path'   => data_path('cache'),
        ],

        'memcached' => [
            'driver'  => 'memcached',
            'servers' => [
                [
                    'host' => env('MEMCACHED_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                    'port' => env('MEMCACHED_PORT', 11211),
                    'weight' => 100,
                ],
            ],
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cache Key Prefix
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When utilizing a RAM based store such as APC or Memcached, there might
    | be other applications utilizing the same cache. So, we'll specify a
    | value to get prefixed to all our keys so we can avoid collisions.
    |
    */

    'prefix' => env('CACHE_PREFIX', 'app_'),


    'lifetime' => [
        'default' => 120
    ],

];
?>
```

**MemcachedConnector**

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Cache;

use Memcached;
use RuntimeException;

class MemcachedConnector
{
    /**
     * Create a new Memcached connection.
     *
     * @param  array  $servers
     * @return \Memcached
     *
     * @throws \RuntimeException
     */
    public function connect(array $servers)
    {
        $memcached = $this->getMemcached();

        // For each server in the array, we'll just extract the configuration and add
        // the server to the Memcached connection. Once we have added all of these
        // servers we'll verify the connection is successful and return it back.
        foreach ($servers as $server) {
            $memcached->addServer(
                $server['host'], $server['port'], $server['weight']
            );
        }

        $memcachedStatus = $memcached->getVersion();

        if (! is_array($memcachedStatus)) {
            throw new RuntimeException('No Memcached servers added.');
        }

        if (in_array('255.255.255', $memcachedStatus) && count(array_unique($memcachedStatus)) === 1) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Could not establish Memcached connection.');
        }

        return $memcached;
    }

    /**
     * Get a new Memcached instance.
     *
     * @return \Memcached
     */
    protected function getMemcached()
    {
        return new memcached;
    }
}
```

I am getting PHP   Fatal error:  Class 'Memcached' not found in /home/remi/domains/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/MemcachedConnector.php on line 51

Thanks a lot beforehand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `.env` file (root of project), set the following:

```
 CACHE_DRIVER=array
```

This will cause any calls to the cache service to be stored in memory, and purely for the request it has been called in.

---

Alternatively, in your `cache.php` config file, you can change

```
'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'),
```

to:

```
'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'array'),
```

if you don't define `CACHE_DRIVER` in your .env, and want to default to using an array.

Comment: hello, thanx for response. 

I am getting PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Memcached' not found in /home/remi/domains/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/MemcachedConnector.php on line 51